# How to fill an array with while loop?

Tags: java, listview

I've a piece of code something like this and I want to insert the data by using a while.

```
Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]{
                new Weather(0, "Cloudy"),
                new Weather(0, "Showers"),
                new Weather(0, "Snow"),
                new Weather(0, "Storm"),
                new Weather(0, "Sunny")
};
```

How can I fill this list using a while ?

Thanks

Comment: you already filled the array when initialized. do you want to manipulate the content?

Comment: You might get better answers if you told us *why* you want to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[5];

int i = 0;
while(i < weather_data.length){
    //fill array [i]
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want to fill your array with the following String array as base:

```
String[] weatherTypes = {"Cloudy","Showers","Snow","Storm","Sunny"};
```

Then you can do this:

```
int i=0;
Weather[] weather_data = new Weather[];
for (String weatherType: weatherTypes){
   weather_data[i] = new Weather(0,weatherType);
   i++;
}
```

You could use also use a list:

```
List<Weather> weather_data = new ArrayList<Weather>();
for (String weatherType: weatherTypes){
   weather_data.add(new Weather(0,weatherTypes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Weather[] weather_data = new Weather[5];

public void addWeatherData(Weather newWeather) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < weather_data.length) {
        if (weather_data[counter] == null) {
            weather_data[counter] = newWeather;
            return;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```